# training Hopefield network with encog in java

Tags: java, neural-network, encog

I started working with this network. And I wrote some code, but I am not sure whether I am doing it right or not. here is what I do:

- First create the network `HopefieldNetwork net = new HopefieldNetwork(50)`.
- Than add all patterns, with `net.addPattern(aPattern)` where `aPattern` is of type `BasicMLData` and changes in a loop to add all patterns.
- Now do `net.runUntilStable(5000)` for training with 5000 iterations max. Is this right?
- Now we have the trained network. Get output like `out = (BasicMLData) net.compute(input)`

So is everything OK?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Are the results suprising? The actual code, with information you wrote here provided in the comments would be much more valuable for any analyzis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

You have to call `setCurrentState` then `runUntilStable` then `getCurrentState` to get output.